# How to manage Cost Function while combining classification and regression?

Tags: machine-learning, python, tensorflow

I want to predict two values in a Machine learning model. The first is the direction (1 or 0 - Classification problem) and the second is magnitude (number).

I want to provide more weight to classification so currently this is the cost i am using:

```
classcost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y[:, 0], logits=AL[:, 0]))
reggcost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y[:, 1] - AL[:, 1]))

cost = 0.7 * classcost + 0.3 * reggcost
```

However the regression cost decreases very fast (goes from 0.75 to 0.004 in a couple of iterations) while the classification cost does not (goes from 0.7 in couple of 100 iterations than to 0.4 and stabilizes). I think this causes issues with regression results.

What would be the right way to tell my model this information?

Answer (score 1):

You can weight the regression higher at the start so that after it quickly decreases, it is still on the same order of magnitude as the classification loss.

Another thing you can do is to make the weights on each loss a function of the current time-step, so that the coefficient on the regression loss increases after the first few iterations.